# How to print distribution name and version

Tags: terminal, version

In the terminal for macOS Ventura, how can I print the distribution name and version? I want to see something like unix xyz.

Comment: Does the terminal show that output when you Execute `uname` ?

Comment: Check Details here :: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/368243/how-can-i-identify-the-macos-version-from-the-command-line :: You can then Extract the necessary Distribution Name & Version.